# How to find array items that occur at least K times

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose I have an array of `N` integers. I need to find the integers that occur at least `K` times in the array. Can I do it in `O(N)` with `O(1)` memory ?

Obviously, I can either sort the array or use a hash map. Can I do better than that ?

Comment: Are there any additional constraints on `K`? It is possible to do it better for `K = N / 2` or `K = N / 3`, for example.

Comment: In may case `K << N`, e.g. `N is 10^5` and `K = 5`

Comment: Why not store the integers along with there frequency and keep that list sorted by frequency?

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you. What is the complexity of this algorithm ?

Comment: How do you get to O(1) for memory?

Comment: @EdHeal Ok. Suppose I need  just _the number_ of elements that occur at least K times.

Comment: Storage for the data will at mode O(N). To get the list will be O(k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you cannot do it in O(n) and O(1) time without any restriction on the input.

This is a generalization of the [**element distinctness problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) (element distinctness is basically this problem with `k=2`), and it cannot be solved in O(n) time with O(1) memory.

The alternatives are (as you suggested, just adding complexity information):

1. Sort and iterate - `O(nlogn)` time, very little extra space
2. Use Histogram based on hash-table to count occurances of each element. `O(n)` average case time, `O(n^2)` worst case time, `O(n)` space.

Note that because of the reduction from element distinctness, you cannot even tell if there is *any* number that occures `k` or more times with your restrictions, let alone find it or count how many of them exist.

Answer (score 2):

If say  numbers are only 10^5 at max, make a frequency array F[10^5+1] and do the following, assuming numbers are in arr[] ( 0 based index). vector < int > ans stores your answer.

```
vector< int >ans;
for( i = 0 ; i <= 100000 ; i++ ) F[i] = 0;
for(i=0 ; i < N ; i++ )
{
    F[arr[i]]++;
    if(F[arr[i]]==K)
    {
         ans.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Time Complexity is O(N) and constant memory is there ( an array of 10^5 if integers are always <=10^5 ) apart from ans which can take O(N) memory in worst case but you can't do anything about that.

Comment: What if `arr[i]` is very large (say `1000000000` or more). Better to use hash maps.

Comment: yes if integer are greater than 10^7 will have to use hash map but Michael said in comments numbers are <=10^5. But yes in general hash map is better to use

Comment: OP said `N <= 10^5` means numbers are less than `10^5` but value of individual number can be anything upto MAX_INT. Even if individual number is less than `10^5` space complexity of your code will be very high. Suppose array has only two numbers still you are using `10^5` sized array.

Comment: yeah i read it wrong thanks anyways if numbers are less than 10^7 we can use the above method otherwise you are right about hash map